# No module named using sys.path.append

Tags: python, django, path, importerror

I'm trying import models from my Django project to another project. I found two solutions:
first using os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] and second using sys.path.append(). My project structure:

-Project1(Django Project) 
 - mysite 
      - settings.py 
      - ... 
  - app1 
      - models.py 
      - ...

Project2(no Django Project) 
  - test 
      - dog.py

And in dog.py file:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append("/home/jack/workspace/Project1/mysite")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] ="mysite.settings"
from app1 import models
```

But console show me:

```
from app1 import models
ImportError: No module named app1
```

Comment: I would just add app 1 to your sys path, then import models.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be adding path to `mysite` package, not `Project1`. But `app1` is located in `Project1`, so Python can't find it.

Try this:

```
sys.path.append("/home/jack/workspace/Project1")
```

Answer (score 2):

From your drawing, `app1` is a sibling to `mysite`—that is, it's in `/home/jack/workspace/Project1/app1/`, not `/home/jack/workspace/Project1/mysite/app1/`.

So, `sys.path.append("/home/jack/workspace/Project1/mysite")` isn't going to do you any good; you need `sys.path.append("/home/jack/workspace/Project1/")'.